# Move IIS logs to S3

Tags: iis-7, logging, amazon-s3

I have a requirement to move IIS logs to S3 directly. There are tools that can be used to create a mount and set IIS to have logging to mounted S3 bucket.

My question is is there a way where I can do it from IIS level. I was suggested this article

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904694/moving-files-to-amazon-s3-while-keeping-urls

But I am not sure how I can implement the above scenario on IIS logs.

Can any one help me with this.

- Does the approach given in URL works for IIS logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked article deals with content redirection that you're serving from the site -- all configurable within IIS.

Log output is completely different and IIRC rather short on configuration options. Last time I looked the only log output options built-in to IIS were where to write the logs files which means you're stuck with paths it gets from windows.

Comment: Thanks for replaying That means that article is not useful? You mean I should have a third party tool to upload the logs to S3 ?

Comment: Yup.  s3cmd is easy and free as Abhishek Anand Amralkar said in the next comment.  In any case you'll need to install _something_ to make this work.

Comment: I found an tool which work with no installation http://sprightlysoft.com/S3Sync/ it is .NET based tool. I started using it. So far no issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use S3cmd to transfer log file from your Windows machine to S3

```
 1) Setup python 2.x - Python 3 is not supported.
 2) Download s3cmd from www.s3tools.org
 3) Add python directory to your global path (should be C:\python2x)
 4) Run python setup.py install
 5) Run python s3cmd --configure (from the build path)
```

You can edit the values in the setup configuration at c:\Users\"username"\AppData\Roaming\ in a file called s3cmd.ini

Then you can run commands, example:

```
 python s3cmd ls - it should list your buckets.
```

Once this is done you can srite batch script to upload logs.

Comment: I will check that alternate also. I have explored this but installing Python in so many servers and configuring is an issue. Any way thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I found an alternate at http://sprightlysoft.com/S3Sync/ which works without python.